# Laravel - old inputs on create method

Tags: php, laravel, forms, input

I have a small project with laravel and I stuck on my `create method` inputs. So this is happening:

[image]

When I click on my input to type something it is showing my old values. How can I get rid of that?

Here is my `Controller@store` function:

```
     /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->name == 'Optika Podgorica/Delta'){
            $this->validate($request, [
                'br_kesice' => 'required',
                'klijent' => 'required',
                'datum_preuz' => 'required',
                //'datum_izdav' => 'required',
            ]);

            $storeone = new Storeone;
            $storeone->br_kesice = $request->input('br_kesice');
            $storeone->klijent = $request->input('klijent');
            $storeone->br_telefona = $request->input('br_telefona');
            $storeone->posao = $request->input('posao');
            $storeone->cijena = $request->input('cijena');
            $storeone->placanje = $request->input('placanje');
            $storeone->popust = $request->input('popust');
            $storeone->datum_preuz = $request->input('datum_preuz');
            $storeone->datum_izdav = $request->input('datum_izdav');
            $storeone->smjena = $request->input('smjena');
            $storeone->radnik = $request->input('radnik');
            $storeone->status = $request->input('status');
            $storeone->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $storeone->save();

            return redirect('/storeones');
        }else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

And I use `Laravel Collective` forms. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's coming form browser auto fill.  Add  autocomplete="false" to your input it will not show previous entry.

Comment: "Autocomplete=off" is completely ignored by chrome since like 5 years ago. You might generate a random autocomplete value to this attribute and it probably will not autocomplete anymore.

Comment: I just put ```autocomplete="off"``` and it is working